# PIP or PIP3 broken. AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'ERR_load_RAND_strings'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

This error message appears when I attempt to install something using pip or pip3. I tried numerous approaches to fix the problem, but none were successful.

**Using PIP**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 18, in module>
    from pip._internal.download import PipSession
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 15, in module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six, urllib3
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 97, in module
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 169, in module>
    _lib.ERR_load_RAND_strings()
    AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'ERR_load_RAND_strings'
```

**Using PIP3**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 5, in module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 18, in module>
    from pip._internal.download import PipSession
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 15, in module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six, urllib3
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 97, in module
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 169, in module>
    _lib.ERR_load_RAND_strings()
    AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'ERR_load_RAND_strings'
```

**List that I tried**

1. Reinstall python3
2. Reinstall python3-pip
3. /usr/local/bin/python3.10 -m pip3 install --upgrade pip
4. apt install python3-pip-whl
5. python -m pip install pip==18.0

and more but none of them worked.

I can reinstall OS because it's installed in my HOST. I am not using a VM.

```
My Version:-
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="2022.3"
VERSION_ID="2022.3"
VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="https://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.kali.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.kali.org/"
```

Comment: What were the "numerous approaches" you tried?

Comment: @MattDmo I just update that

Comment: What OS and OS version are you using?

Comment: I am using kali 2022.3

Comment: What is the exact `pip3` command you're running that creates this error message? What package are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

i see that the error has something to do with

```
**from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL**
```

try using `import OpenSSL` instead
or try to reinstall/update the OpenSSL module

also what module are you trying to install, maybe there is a compatibility issue

Comment: I did reinstall OpenSSL did't worked. How how can I import openSSL. I am using kali 2022 I try to install several module, but main thing is I can't even view the version of the pip when I try to it gaves me same error. pip3 --version or pip --version